# Did Saori also have feelings for Kyousuke?

Tags: oreimo

In *Ore no Imouto ga Konna ni Kawaii Wake ga Nai*, almost all the girls confessed their feelings to Kyousuke, and

> even Kanako confessed when Kyousuke came to her concert.

In OreImo season two, when they were discussing (fighting) about who was going to accompany and support Kyousuke on his new apartment, Saori also insisted that she was supposed to do so. Did she also have feelings for him or did she only tease him? Do they explain this in the light novel?

Comment: I have not read the novel but as a watcher of the anime, it seems rather clear to me that Saori also have a crush on him but since this is my opinion I will keep it as a comment.

Comment: I think Saori think of Kyousuke as only a friend, but again it's just my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, in the light novel, Saori never confessed to Kyousuke, nor in the anime. Saori did insisted that she's the best to take care of Kyousuke like you mentioned. But this seems more like she did that so that she stays true to her Saori Bajeena character, rather than a real romantic feelings towards Kyousuke.

The possible reason for this is that at that time, all the other girls insisted on taking care of Kyousuke. It fits Saori Bajeena's cheerful persona more if she were to also join the fray rather than staying quiet.

Another possibility for her behavior was that at that time there were Kuroneko and Kanako competing for the position. Saori surely knows who they are to Kirino. Were Kirino to choose either one, the other is surely to be hurt. Saori proposed herself so that Kirino won't be troubled choosing between the two (three if you count Manami, but Kirino won't choose her anyway).

It should be noted that in the end Kirino chose Ayase instead of Saori. Possibly because Kiririn felt that Saori is also attracted to Kyousuke. This is not likely though, since Ayase actually has a feeling towards Kyousuke and she still chose her.

Source: I read the novel.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the [relationship](http://oreimo.wikia.com/wiki/Saori_Makishima#Relationships) between Saori and Kyousuke there seem to be some feeling but its not shown exactly what type of feeling did Saori have with Kyousuke. Yes the feeling is more toward love.

> Overall their relationship with each other remained platonic at best. Despite Kyousuke's shock after discovering Saori's ojou-sama side, the two continued to act normally. In conclusion, Saori is only one of the few female characters who hasn't shown any signs of romantic attraction towards Kyousuke.

Which shows that they are more like friend but

> In the game version, Happy End (PlayStation 3) and Tsuzuku Wake ga nai (PlayStation Portable), they have their own route and in the nearly end, the wedding day of Kyousuke and Saori appeared.

I cannot confirm the exact feeling of Saori towards Kyousuke. And all most every girls confessed Kyousuke, so why leave Saori alone.